# How to pass a PDF file to GlSurfaceView and render it?

Tags: android, image, pdf, glsurfaceview

I am new to openGlSurfaceView in android. I want to pass a PDF file to this surface view. Also I want to include a zoom in/out option for the PDF file. As I came across, drawing triangle and its 3D view, rotation only given. Can any one help me in doing this? Is there any specific tutorial for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a PDF file you need a PDF library. For example Poppler is an open source one. It's not a straightforward thing, like rendering a bitmap.

Comment: Yes.I am using Sun pdf library. In this they are rendering a pdf page as bitmap only. Now i wanted to pass this bitmap into surface view using OpenGl SurfaceView.